# Unable to Connect to Postgres Server Remotely

Tags: postgresql

I set up a Postgres server on my computer (windows) at home just to run some basic work when I am away from home, but I am unable to connect to it outside of my home network. I have setup my pg_hba.conf file to accept connections from my laptop and I have set listen_addresses to '*'. It works perfectly fine if my laptop is on the same network as my home computer, but if I go to any other network it fails to even recognize the connection.

Returns the following in pgAdmin4:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like your home computer is behind a [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) router or a firewall (or both). Have you configured [port fowarding](https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/general-port-forwarding-guide/) on your router at home to allow remote access to your database?

Comment: Thanks for the blazing fast reply. I must confess that I completely ignored the router side of the configuration. It would make sense that the router config would be the source of the issue though. I will look into it later when I get back home. Thanks!

Comment: As I was setting up port-forwarding, I realized that I was using my router's default 192.168.xxx.x.x ip address, which maybe blocking remote access as well. What IP address should I be using for access to the data that is stored on specifically on the host device? IPv4?

Comment: Most home routers use NAT, which means your internal IP and external IP will be different. Most residential routers live at 192.168.x.1 and assign addresses to your computers in the 192.168.x.2 to 192.168.x.254 range. For port forwarding you'll want to use your PC's internally assigned address. Only your router gets an external address [assigned by your ISP](https://www.whatismyip.com/). You'll use this IP to talk to your database, because you set up port forwarding the port will get forwarded to your internal computer.

Comment: Okay so that is the real root of the problem here. So the port forwarding address that I set up should be the address that the router assigns to my device (192.168.x.x) and the actual postgres server itself should be set to the external ip address? Do I have this right?

Comment: Correct, port forwarding should use your PC's internal IP. When connecting to your database from outside your network use the external IP of your router.

Comment: This worked like a charm! Appreciate all of your help!